# How to mix server side code in razor

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

A trivial question but the solution escapes me at the moment

We have a CMS where the Layout and CSS ( names only, no extension ) are retrieved from db !

the .cshtml has this code which does NOT compile cleanly

```
....
 <link href="~/Content/themes/@ViewBag.dbConfig.Theme/style/@ViewBag.dbConfig.CssName.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

where the variable is

```
  ViewBag.dbConfig.CssName
```

without the .css extension

Is there a way to make this work without changing the config ?

Comment: Like javascript's Eval function?

Comment: Why you don't build the entire path in the controller and then add to the ViewBag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would wrap your variable usages... See if that yields something more in line with what you expected.

```
<link href="~/Content/themes/@(ViewBag.dbConfig.Theme)/style/@(ViewBag.dbConfig.CssName).css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

use parantesese and trim:

```
<link href="~/Content/themes/@(ViewBag.dbConfig.Theme.trim())/style/@(ViewBag.dbConfig.CssName.trim()+".css")" rel="stylesheet">
```